# How to get option values in widget development

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to learn WordPress' Widgets API and create my own widgets.

**The problem:** When I try to echo `$instance['platform']`, nothing appears.

I want to be able to get the value.

```
class Practice_Widget extends WP_Widget
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $widget_ops = array(
            'classname' => 'my-widget',
            'description' => 'Second Widget'
        );
        parent::__construct('my_little_widget', 'Practice Second', $widget_ops);
    }

    public function widget($args, $instance)
    {
        echo $args['before_widget'];
        echo $instance['platform'];             
        echo $args['after_widget'];
    }

    public function form ($instance)
    {
        ?>
        <p>
            <label for = "<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('title')); ?>">
                Title: 
            </label>
            <select name="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_name('platform')); ?>)">
                <option value="face">Facebook</option>
                <option value="insta">Instagram</option>
            </select>
        </p>
    <?php
    }

    public function update ($new_instance, $old_instance)
    {
        $instance = array();
        $instance['platform'] = ! empty($new_instance['platform']) ? $new_instance['platform'] : '';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `update()` function needs to **return** the `$instance` array, otherwise WordPress won't be able to save the new values (hence the reason why you don't see anything on the front-end):

```
public function update ($new_instance, $old_instance)
{
    $instance = array();
    $instance['platform'] = ! empty($new_instance['platform']) ? $new_instance['platform'] : '';

    return $instance;
}
```

See the [Widgets API documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API) for more details.

Comment: Also, you'll want to [enable the debug log](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/#wp_debug_log) so you can spot issues with your code as you write it / test it. It'll make your life so much easier and your code less prone to bugs.

Comment: Thank you so much. Also thanks for debugging mode, I didn't know that.